# SharePoint - client API - without NET, MFC/C++?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, mfc

Does a SharePoint client API exist for C++, MFC users?

There's a NET one, but I prefer to access without using NET.

Comment: This one works for all languages as long as they can talk to soap services, http://camelottoolkit.codeplex.com/

Comment: I need one which requires nothing to be installed on server. Any ideas? I guess web-services would be the way to go.

Comment: Well the toolkit + the required ADO.NET Connector could be installed anywhere. It simply needs access to SharePoint over the net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no C++ API, but you can access all webservices through C++ if you really want to.
I guess Managed C++ would be easier though.